# Why does Webpack rebuild JS on CSS changes?

Tags: webpack, css-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I use `mini-css-extract-plugin`, `css-loader` and `sass-loader`.

Output on CSS change:

```
    Built at: 06/07/2019 7:37:09 PM
                   Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    vendor.css   174 KiB  vendor  [emitted]         vendor
vendor.css.map   188 KiB  vendor  [emitted]         vendor
     vendor.js  3.25 MiB  vendor  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
 vendor.js.map  3.27 MiB  vendor  [emitted]         vendor
 + 4 hidden assets
Entrypoint core [big] = vendor.css vendor.js vendor.css.map vendor.js.map core.css core.js core.css.map core.js.map
[./static/sass/base.scss] 39 bytes {core} [built]
    + 648 hidden modules
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?url=false&sourceMap=true!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?&sourceMap=true!static/sass/base.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?url=false&sourceMap=true!./static/css/minicolors-2.2.4.css] 195 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
        + 10 hidden modules
```

As I assume this is because Webpack is basically a JS bundler, so CSS is bundled to JS and `mini-css-extract-plugin` extracts CSS to a separate chunk. Is that accurate?

Why does Webpack rebuild JS output files when only my styles change?